# How to click item inside ListView in android using appium?

Tags: android, appium

I am not getting any way to click item inside from listview

can any body help me to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the way how to click item inside listview

// Find and click inside listview

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("com.sample:id/list"))
    list.get(0).click()
```

Comment: I know this is old but what if is being used in the above? In my project I can't see the list items with appium inspector. They look like a block.

Comment: is List UI coming from any kind of lib, if ID  is not showing in UI inspector, then you need to perform by Text elements

Answer (score 0):

List view is a dynamic one ,so I suggest you to provide screenshot for the issue. Try below one

List Completed_check = ds.findElements(By.id(c_invoice_number));

          //where i is the index
 
Completed_check.get(i).click();